# Spring Oauth2 Provider in Grails - dependency

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I want to enable OAuth2 provider in my web application, which is based on Grails 2.2.2. However I'm struggling with spring-security-oauth2-provider plugin.

spring-security-oauth2-provider plugin uses spring-security-oauth2 library. I'm trying to run plugin version 1.0.4-SNAPSHOT from Git, which uses **spring-security-oauth2-1.0.4.RELEASE** library.

After plugin installation, my application will not start, saying that it could not initialize **"oauth2ProviderFilter"** bean with this exception and stack trace:

```
| Error 2013-06-15 23:51:51,434 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'oauth2ProviderFilter': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'oauth2ProviderFilter': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:122)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:925)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:472)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.DefaultRuntimeSpringConfiguration.getApplicationContext(DefaultRuntimeSpringConfiguration.java:153)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:170)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:127)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsConfigUtils.configureWebApplicationContext(GrailsConfigUtils.java:121)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoader.java:107)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4887)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5381)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
    at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.validateConstructorArguments(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.<init>(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.make(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeParameterizedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.generics.repository.ConstructorRepository.getParameterTypes(ConstructorRepository.java:94)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.getGenericParameterTypes(Method.java:291)
    at java.beans.FeatureDescriptor.getParameterTypes(FeatureDescriptor.java:387)
    at java.beans.MethodDescriptor.setMethod(MethodDescriptor.java:114)
    at java.beans.MethodDescriptor.<init>(MethodDescriptor.java:72)
    at java.beans.MethodDescriptor.<init>(MethodDescriptor.java:56)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getTargetMethodInfo(Introspector.java:1130)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:414)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:161)
    at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.<init>(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.forClass(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:142)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getCachedIntrospectionResults(BeanWrapperImpl.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyDescriptors(BeanWrapperImpl.java:331)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.filterPropertyDescriptorsForDependencyCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1242)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1101)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
```

After investigationg on oauth2 library documentation ([here](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security-oauth/wiki/oAuth2)), I found out that `oauth2ProviderFilter` is an instance of `OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter`. After inspecting source of this class ([github](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/authentication/OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java)), it looks like there are few properties (`authenticationEntryPoint`, `authenticationManager`, `authencticationDetailsSource`) that need to be instantiated. I thought that there might be a problem with dependency injection, so I tried to define `oauth2ProviderFilter` bean in resources.groovy with references to instances defined by `Spring Security Core` plugin.

I placed this in my resources.groovy:

```
beans = {
    oauth2ProviderFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter){
        authenticationEntryPoint = ref('basicAuthenticationEntryPoint')
        authenticationManager = ref('authenticationManager')
        authenticationDetailsSource = ref('authenticationDetailsSource')
    }
}
```

That did not solve the problem, there is still error saying that this filter can't be instantiated.

Since I'm no spring expert, do you think that this error might be connected with dependency injection during bean creation? Where  might be the problem?

Is it possible that spring-security-oauth2 library is designed for spring framework version which and grails might be using different framework version and this might cause problems?

What are next steps I could take to find the cause of the problem and eventually fix the problem?

Comment: I know this is an old issue, but do you by any chance remember how did you solve it? I have the exact same problem right now (grails 2.2.4, :spring-security-oauth2-provider:1.0.5.2)

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you run the release version of the plugin and not the SNAPSHOT? I found that when I work with latest versions of grails, many times they break existing plugins. So what I would do is...

1. Try to use release version of plugin with your 2.2.2 grails.
2. If that does not work, I would step back my grails version and try an older one with the released plugin.
3. If an older version does not work, I might be missing something in my setup, so I would try to figure out what it is.
4. If things work in older versions and it looks like my setup is good based on setting it up, then I would ask on the [grails nabble](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Grails-user-f1312389.html) on what is up and/or open a [JIRA ticket](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS).

Another thing to consider is how young/old the plugin is and how many previous bugs it had. We have many times either decided to debug the plugin because it was a worthwhile effort, but sometimes we decided to not use it because it had too many issues and were going to keep us back in the future.

Comment: Actually author (or maintainer) of the plugin recently upgraded plugin to 2.2.2 grails version and upgraded to spring-security-oauth2 1.0.4.RELEASE.